# Trying to use node.js, keep getting errors

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I installed node.js because I needed a way for storing my javascript variables into a mysql database (I use phpmyadmin).

I'm getting this error and I just don't now what to do with it:

```
C:\Users\Robin> npm install mysql
C:\Users\Robin
`-- mysql@2.13.0

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Robin\package.json'

npm WARN Robin No description

npm WARN Robin No repository field.

npm WARN Robin No README data

npm WARN Robin No license field.
```

I also typed another command (can't remember which one) and it gave me a list of what looks like usernames and email-accounts.

I have no idea which steps I need to take for succesfully installing node.js and make it work. I checked youtube video's and stuff but there like worthless.

So my question from scrath is: I installed node.js, how to make it work?

Kind regards from the Netherlands

Comment: they are **WARN**ING not ERROR ... try `npm init` first, to create a `package.json`

Comment: C:\Users\Robin>npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.

It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.


I'm getting further!

Comment: yes, I know what npm init does thank you, I suggest you follow the prompts rather than posting every little thing your PC does from now on :p

Comment: I only don't understand what to do now:

Sorry, name can only contain url friendly characters

Comment: uninstall nodeJS from control panel and try install once again.

Comment: don't follow @rajpeer uninformed advice

Comment: I'm retarded but not that retarted haha. But thanks @JaromandaX

Comment: I would never call anyone on SO retarded (well, never again :p )

Comment: Hahaha @JaromandaX

Answer (score 1):

Well, I may get your problem . Then i searched and found some valuable steps for you from the internet .

Create a new project: mkdir mysql-test && cd mysql-test.

Create a package.json file: npm init -y.

Install the mysql module: npm install mysql.

Create an app.js file and copy in the snippet below (editing the placeholders as appropriate).
Run the file: node app.js. Observe a “Connected!” message

Here is the Url where i got these information :https://www.sitepoint.com/using-node-mysql-javascript-client/

Best of luck .

Answer (score 0):

You need have package.json file. 
Do first:

```
npm init
```

Then you will have package.json. Now you can do:

```
npm install package
```

Or

```
npm install package --save (for save dependencies in package.json)
```

EDIT:

Iam trying do npm intall in a void folder in my coputer:

```
diego.martin@csa-188:~/Proyectos/pruebas/prueba$ npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
name: (prueba) Hello
Sorry, name can no longer contain capital letters.
name: (prueba) hello
version: (1.0.0) 
description: None
entry point: (index.js) 
test command: 
git repository: 
keywords: 
author: Diego
license: (ISC) 
About to write to /home/diego.martin/Proyectos/pruebas/prueba/package.json:

{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "None",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Diego",
  "license": "ISC"
}


Is this ok? (yes) yes
```

Then i have packaje.json:

```
diego.martin@csa-188:~/Proyectos/pruebas/prueba$ ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  2 diego.martin diego.martin 4096 jul  5 13:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 diego.martin diego.martin 4096 jul  5 13:25 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 diego.martin diego.martin  210 jul  5 13:30 package.json
diego.martin@csa-188:~/Proyectos/pruebas/prueba$
```

Lastest:

```
diego.martin@csa-188:~/Proyectos/pruebas/prueba$ npm install mysql --save
hello@1.0.0 /home/diego.martin/Proyectos/pruebas/prueba
└─┬ mysql@2.13.0 
  ├── bignumber.js@3.1.2 
  ├─┬ readable-stream@1.1.14 
  │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2 
  │ ├── inherits@2.0.3 
  │ ├── isarray@0.0.1 
  │ └── string_decoder@0.10.31 
  └── sqlstring@2.2.0 

npm WARN hello@1.0.0 No repository field.
diego.martin@csa-188:~/Proyectos/pruebas/prueba$
```

Comment: when insert: npm init it gives me this: this utility walks.... blabla. en then:

name: (Robin)


then i type: npm install package and it keeps saying: sorry, name can only contain url friendly characters

Comment: Wait! It got me somewhere. I can create a package: 

discription:

entry point:

etc etc.

What should I fill in there?



I'm having a half our break from work, be right back!

Comment: Do `npm init -y` so it doesn't ask you anything

Comment: What do you have in the directory where you are trying npm init?